# PHP Register: SQL not adding items

Tags: php, sql

After I input the fields and press "Register" my Database is not getting affected at all.
My HTML code:

```
<div id="register_details"><?php require_once('functions/reg.php');?>
<form action="" method="post" id="loginForm">
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
<td>Email ID&#42; &#58; &nbsp;</td>
<td><input class="input" type="text" name="email" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password&#42; &#58; &nbsp;</td>
<td><input class="input" type="password" name="password" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="right"><input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
```

This is my php file:

```
<?php
require_once 'sys.class.php';
$reg = new Registration;
$reg->SetEmail($_POST['email']);
$reg->SetPassword($_POST['password']);
$error = $reg->InsertUserToSql(); // see notes at the class

if(!empty($error['2']))
{
echo $error['2'];
}
?>
```

The error are in these 2 only. My `sys.class.php` file is Ok.

Comment: Does it work if you hardwire values into `SetEmail` and `SetPassword`?

Comment: Wich is the error? Where is your SQL clause? Wich RDBMS are you using, MySQL or other?

Comment: you are missing the value for the ``action`` attribute in ``<form>``-tag

Comment: and please consider using a different code style... ugly as hell.... function names starting with big letters? C'mon...

Comment: That was my main question. I guessed that I did wrong here. How do I take in values there??I mean the user enters data in the HTML file. So how to transfer those values to this php code??

Comment: show the InsertUserToSql(); method,you have to pass values of email and password in the parameter of InsertUserToSql method

Comment: impossible to answer without knowing what class Registration does (and how).

Comment: All my functions are in a single file. I took it from an external source. Its quite big. How do I share it here?

Comment: i think you store all the functions in 1 class(Registration) and by including this class you create the object and call the methods of this class but if you want to pass values in this methods than you have to pass the values in to the parameters of method.

Comment: "I took it from an external source" - then you could provide a link to that source...

Answer (score 1):

you have to make change in your code like this

```
<?php
require_once 'sys.class.php';
$reg = new Registration;
$email=$reg->SetEmail($_POST['email']);
$pass=$reg->SetPassword($_POST['password']);
$error = $reg->InsertUserToSql($emai,$pass); //pass the values to the method

if(!empty($error['2']))
{
echo $error['2'];
}
?>
```

At your Registration class,in `InsertUserToSql()`

```
function InsertUserToSql($email,$pass){
$sql="INSERT INTO tbl_name(`email`,`pass`) values(".$email.",".$pass.")";

}
```

so like the above code you can pass this values and use in Registration class.

Comment: My function:
`function InsertUserToSql()
    {
        $error = $this->Validate();
        if(count($error) > 0 )
        {
                return $error;    
        }
        else
        {

        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO users (password, email, regdate) VALUES (:password, :email, :regdate)");
        
        $stmt->bindParam(':password', $this->Password);
        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $this->Email);
        $stmt->bindParam(':regdate', time());
        $stmt->execute();
        $arr = array();
        $arr = $stmt->errorInfo();
        return $arr;
        }
    } `

Comment: i dont know much about the PDO but you have to pass the values in the method,forum doesnt give you the exact answer.jus make some logic and implement it from my answer.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I'll tell you if i succeed.

Comment: you are also missing some functionality  like action in <form> tag so be concentrate there also.

Comment: Actually, I can code in PHP. But this PDO thing is giving me problems. I was converting everything to PDO.